# How to update BinData array into Object array in MongoDB using UpdateMany

Tags: mongodb

```
**Sample Update Query:-**
This is sample update query
    db.getCollection('Sanple_Product_Collection').updateMany(
        { "Products": { $type: 5 } },
        {
            $set: {
                'Products.$': { _id: "$Products", ProductName: null, ProductType: 1 }
            }
        }
    )
```

Need to have products Bin Data array into Objects of _id, Product Name, Product Type array.
Array's UUID need to use in Product's _id as input from existing records.

```
**Sample Document** 

    Products : [ 
        UUID("05d00bff-ce13-4230-961c-499419990032"),
        UUID("7bf033b1-fc99-4b92-aac7-4a6c30b94913"),
        UUID("d4185c4c-56ba-4580-b8e3-d17d43d3d7fa")
        ]
    
    
**Actual Output:-**

    Products : [
        { _id: "$Products", ProductName: null, ProductType: 1 }
        { _id: "$Products", ProductName: null, ProductType: 1 }
        { _id: "$Products", ProductName: null, ProductType: 1 }
    ]
Getting above invalid output.

**Expected Output:-**

    Products : [
        { _id: UUID("05d00bff-ce13-4230-961c-499419990032"), ProductName: null, ProductType: 1 }
        { _id: UUID("7bf033b1-fc99-4b92-aac7-4a6c30b94913"), ProductName: null, ProductType: 1 }
        { _id: UUID("d4185c4c-56ba-4580-b8e3-d17d43d3d7fa"), ProductName: null, ProductType: 1 }
    ]
```

Need to have above as expected output

Answer (score 0):

*based on your requirement we can actually do like this *
*if this is not you looking for then elaborate more*

```
 let Products = [ 
        UUID("05d00bff-ce13-4230-961c-499419990032"),
        UUID("7bf033b1-fc99-4b92-aac7-4a6c30b94913"),
        UUID("d4185c4c-56ba-4580-b8e3-d17d43d3d7fa")
        ]

for(let item of products){
   await Sanple_Product_Collection.updateOne({},{$set: { _id: item,ProductName: null, ProductType: 1 },{upsert: true});
};
```

Comment: Products is one of the document in the collection, Sanple_Product_Collection have 20 other documents.

Do I need to loop through each document and store Products  in an array variable and do updateOne() query for each item in array?

db.getCollection('Sanple_Product_Collection').find(
        { "Products": { $type: 5 } });

I need to use above find() in ForEach loop, as collection is very large it will take lot of time to complete the update query.